# How to silence keyboard clicks on macOS

Tags: mac

I am using macOS 10.12 Sierra on a MacBook Air. How do I silence the clicks on my keyboard. Pressing the mute button does not mute the clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure these sounds aren't the mechanical clicks of the keyboard?

Comment: I agree with this answer. AFAIK, there have never been artificial keyboard sounds in OS X (MacOS)